# why tomcat8.exe does not work?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I have downloaded tomcat 8.0.14 (x64 version of windows).
I start tomcat with success (I run startup.bat).
I have JAVA_HOME, CATALINA_HOME and everything works well!

In my tomcat, here is tomcat8.exe file, i think it it for to register as service. When I double click to it, nothing happens. Here is only black window (CMD) which is for about milliseconds, I cant read even errors too.

Comment: go to your tomcat folder installation \logs and update the question with log files

Comment: Or read [the fine manual](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html).

Comment: Blatant refusal to do any prior research before asking.